# Linux rpm relocate package to multiple prefixes

Tags: rpm-spec

Let us suppose the package installs files under different folders i.e under /opt, /etc, etc. Is it possible to create relocatable package which installs files to different prefixes for each partition like /opt to /abc/opt and /etc to /abc/etc or /xyz/etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your spec file prefix looks like this

```
  Prefix: /usr
  Prefix: /etc
```

you can relocate files to different prefixes using command

```
rpm ... --relocate /opt=/abc/opt --relocate /etc=/xyz/etc ...
```